# Getting data from list view clicked position

Tags: android

I am using following method to populate a listview from a remote JSON file:

```
private class GetHttpResponseReuniones extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    public Context context;




    String ResultHolder;

    List<SubastasHome> subastasHomeList;

    public GetHttpResponseReuniones(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
    {




        String URLFinal = ServerURLReuniones;



        HttpServicesClass httpServiceObject = new HttpServicesClass(URLFinal);
        try
        {
            httpServiceObject.ExecutePostRequest();

            if(httpServiceObject.getResponseCode() == 200)
            {
                ResultHolder = httpServiceObject.getResponse();

                if(ResultHolder != null)
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;

                    try {
                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(ResultHolder);

                        JSONObject jsonObject;

                        SubastasHome SubastasHome;

                        subastasHomeList = new ArrayList<SubastasHome>();

                        for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++)
                        {
                            SubastasHome = new SubastasHome();

                            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            Log.d("SUBASTAS ","SUBASTAS:"+jsonObject);

                            SubastasHome.id_subasta = jsonObject.getString("id_subasta");
                            SubastasHome.marca = jsonObject.getString("marca");
                            SubastasHome.modelo = jsonObject.getString("modelo");
                            SubastasHome.ano = jsonObject.getString("ano");
                            SubastasHome.foto = jsonObject.getString("foto");
                            SubastasHome.referencia = jsonObject.getString("referencia");
                            SubastasHome.titulo = jsonObject.getString("titulo");
                            SubastasHome.descripcion = jsonObject.getString("descripcion");
                            SubastasHome.empieza = jsonObject.getString("empieza");
                            SubastasHome.termina = jsonObject.getString("termina");
                            SubastasHome.comprador = jsonObject.getString("comprador");
                            SubastasHome.vendedor = jsonObject.getString("vendedor");
                            SubastasHome.puja_ganadora = jsonObject.getString("puja_ganadora");
                            SubastasHome.generacion = jsonObject.getString("generacion");
                            SubastasHome.serie = jsonObject.getString("serie");
                            SubastasHome.motor = jsonObject.getString("motor");
                            SubastasHome.total_pujas = jsonObject.getString("total_pujas");
                            SubastasHome.mejor_precio = jsonObject.getString("mejor_precio");
                            // cumpleanos.SubjectName2 = jsonObject.getString("subjects2");
                            String termina = jsonObject.getString("termina");



                                    //COUNTDOWN here


                                    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                            String datetermina = termina;
                            try {
                                date1 = (Date) formatter.parse(datetermina);
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                            date2 = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

                            diff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
                            Log.d("TERMINA","termina:date diff "+diff);


                                    long dias = TimeUnit.HOURS.toDays(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff));

                                    long horas = (TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff) - TimeUnit.DAYS.toHours(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(diff)));

                                    long mins =(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(diff)));

                                    long seconds = ((TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(diff) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(diff))));

                                    SubastasHome.termina = dias+"d "+horas+"h "+mins+"m ";

                                    if (dias < 0 && horas <0 && mins < 0){
                                        SubastasHome.termina = "Finalizada";
                                    }




                            subastasHomeList.add(SubastasHome);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(context, httpServiceObject.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

    {


        progressBarSubject.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        //CumplesListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if(subastasHomeList != null)
        {
            ListAdapterClassSubastasHome adapter = new ListAdapterClassSubastasHome(subastasHomeList, context);

            SubastasListView.setAdapter(adapter);




        }
    }
}
```

It is working  fine, but now I need to get the data from a clicked row.
I have included this at oncreate method in my fragment:

```
 SubastasListView.setClickable(true);
        SubastasListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {




            }
        });
```

I am getting the item position from the clicked row, but how can I get all data from this item position to further work with them?

For example I would need the data id_subasta for the clicked position.

Comment: Why don't you use `subastasHomeList.get(position)` inside the listener?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal, I do, but I get the position, not the data for that position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String id ;
SubastasListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        id  = subastasHomeList.get(position).id_subasta  ;
        // Similarly Rest of fields can be retrieved on item click

     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it through getter and setter Just made methods like below. Then exection of asyncTask you would need object of the class where async task extended then through its object get the getList method.

```
List<SubastasHome> tempList = new ArrayList<>(); // Create tempList at top of the class..    


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result)

{
    progressBarSubject.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    //CumplesListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(subastasHomeList != null)
    {
        setList(subastasHomeList); // there set the List..
        ListAdapterClassSubastasHome adapter = new ListAdapterClassSubastasHome(subastasHomeList, context);
        SubastasListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}


public void setList(List<SubastasHome> mSubastasHomeList){
    tempList = mSubastasHomeList;
}

public List<SubastasHome> getList(){
    return tempList;
}
```

There make object of the class which has AsyncTask as well as execute the thread.

```
GetHttpResponseReuniones getHttpResp = new GetHttpResponseReuniones();
getHttpResp.execute();


 SubastasListView.setClickable(true);
    SubastasListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView < ? > parent, View view,int position, long id){
        SubastasHome subastasHome = getHttpResp.getList().get(position); // there get object..
        subastasHome.get....() /// get your data from this object.....
    }
}
```